# Library error from a previous user. How do I change the library to my own?

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I've downloaded this plugin and I needed to edit it slightly. When using a specific command ingame in Minecraft, instead of saying *user* has left it should say *user* has disconnected from *server*. Where the message needs to be yellow and the [server] needs to be orange (or gold which is the colorcode i believe). Now I've decompiled the plugin and immediately it says that a library is missing (in Eclipse) before I've even edited anything.

Im really new to JAVA (I've just started learning it for school) and the only thing I needed was a plugin which says "[user] has disconnected from [server]" when a command is typed in. (the main message should be in yellow and the servername should be in Orange or gold as I have stated before. Now I've been stuck for multiple hours and I cant seem to fix my issue.

I've tried editing the buildpath but I have no clue what I'm doing to be honest

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Project 'Prankster' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\CodeBeasty\Downloads\bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3.jar'  Prankster       Build path  Build Path Problem

The C:\USER is not me and I dont know how to fix that message

Answer (score 0):

The project that you are trying to build (in Eclipse I suppose) is missing a dependency.

In this case it's the `bukkit-api`, the library that you need to access what bukkit gives you in Java.

### How to fix:

1. Download the bukkit jar from a website like https://getbukkit.org/ or just compile it with BuildTools.jar (search on google for tutorials)
2. Add it to the User Libraries
3. Remove the old library path
4. Rebuild

I also suggest you read the [bukkit "official" plugin tutorial](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_Tutorial).